# Convert dates stored as text to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So, I import a CSV file into MySQL Workbench and the datetime columns are changed to text. I can't perform any calculations.

How do I convert the entire column from text to datetime? For example the date is in this format `2022-01-13 11:59:47`, how do I change this to datetime?

Comment: Are those valid dates? If so, you can just alter the datatype of column. But create another text column and copy the data there for backup.

Comment: so the date is in this format '2022-01-13 11:59:47', how do I change this to datetime?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable ( t text );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable set t = '2022-01-13 11:59:47';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+---------------------+
| t                   |
+---------------------+
| 2022-01-13 11:59:47 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table mytable modify column t datetime;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `t` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+---------------------+
| t                   |
+---------------------+
| 2022-01-13 11:59:47 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you have any rows in your text column that aren't valid datetime values, they won't be converted successfully. In those cases, they'll turn into NULL. So be careful and create a backup before you do this `alter table`.

Better yet, do this operation on a copy of your data in another table, until you are confident it will work as you expect. Never try a potentially destructive change on the only copy of your data.

Comment: Hi Bill.
This worked. The null values only come when I subtracted the end_date from the start_date. I might be doing that wrongly too

Answer (score 2):

Run the query on your data:

```
select cast(textdate as datetime)
from t;

show warnings;
```

If there are no warnings in the attempted datetime conversion, proceed with alter table:

```
alter table mytable modify column textdate datetime;
```